# Bound on a solution of a recursion problem with non-constant coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have a recursion of the form:
$$a_{n+1} = c_n a_n +b_n$$ with $ 0 \leq c_n \leq \kappa < 1 $ and $b_n \rightarrow 0$. If needed, I can also assume that $b_n = O(n^{-0.5})$.

I need to find some bound $|a_{n+1}| \leq D_n$ and trying to find the tightest $D_n$ possible.

I know that

$$ a_{n+1} = C_n \, \left(a_0 + \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{b_k}{C_k}\right) = C_na_0 +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{C_n}{C_k}b_k$$

with $C_n = \Pi_{k=1}^{n} c_k$.

Hence,

$$|a_{n+1}| \leq C_n a_0 + \sum_{k = 0}^n \kappa^{n-k+1}|b_k|$$

but I don't know how to proceed. If I use Cauchy - Schwarz, then I'm losing the fact that the $\kappa$'s product is the smallest for the first entries, and thus is making the larger elements of the sum smaller.

Is there a way to improve this bound?

Comment: Note that you'll never get a better bound than $a_n = O(b_{n-1})$ (assuming that the $b_n$ are also positive). So a bound that's in the vicinity of that is actually pretty good.

Comment: @GregMartin How can I get rid of the sum?